# Kafka to BigQuery, best way to consume messages

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to receive messages to my BigQuery tables and I want to know what is the best way to consume those messages.
My Kafka servers who are at AWS they produce AVRO messages and from what I saw Dataflow needs receive JSON format messages. So I googled and found an article explaining how to receive messages to PubSub, but on PubSub what I only see in this type of architecture, they create a Kafka VM on GCP to produce the messages.
What I need to know is:

- It's possible to receive AVRO messages on PubSub from external Kafka Servers and then deserialize the message using my Schema, sending it to Dataflow and finally send it to BigQuery tables?
- Or do I need to create a Kafka VM and use it to consume messages from external servers?

This might seem a bit confusing but it is what I am feeling right now. The main goal here is to get messages from Kafka (AVRO format) at AWS and put them on BigQuery tables. If you have any suggestions they are very welcomed

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You can ask user@beam.apache.org about whether the KafkaIO connector supports Avro messages.
If you want to use Pub/Sub as an intermediate medium, Pub/Sub can support Avro: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-avro-records; and Dataflow can read Avro Pub/Sub topics: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/streaming-avro-records-into-bigquery-using-dataflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Kafka Connect BigQuery Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery) may be exactly what you need. It is a Kafka sink connector that allows you to export messages from Kafka directly to BigQuery. The README page provides detailed configuration instructions, including how to let the connector recognize your Kafka queue and how to enter the information for the destination BigQuery table. This connector should be able to retrieve the AVRO schema automatically from your Kafka project.